# Can I run Windows .bat files in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, batch

I want to run a .bat file in ubuntu, but it just opens the text editor. Here's the code of the .bat file(you can play it):

```
@echo off
set /a guessnum=0
set /a answer=%RANDOM%
echo Welcome to the Guessing Game! 
echo. 
echo Try and Guess my Number! 
echo. 
echo. 
goto guess
:guess
set /p guess=
set /a guessnum=%guessnum% +1
if %guess% GTR %answer% ECHO Lower! 
if %guess% LSS %answer% ECHO Higher! 
if %guess% EQU %answer% GOTO EQUAL
goto goto guess
:equal
echo Congratulations, You guessed right!!! 
echo. 
echo It took you %guessnum% guesses. 
echo. 
pause
```

Comment: The file is seen as being text; hence opening in the text editor. Files are marked as executable via `chmod` (or GUI tools) which you didn't do, but the file must have an interpreter installed that knows how to execute it (usually the type of file can be determined, but the shebang on first line is always a safety item to ensure it's interpreted correctly - your file has none).  You'll need to add software that knows how to interpret it, as it's not BASH script, not perl, not python, not CSH etc...

Comment: This code is erroneous, so there is no output from this batch file. The statement `goto top` can't be executed because there is no label named `:top` in this batch file. Debugging batch files is off topic at Ask Ubuntu. Try asking for help at a Windows site or Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, most of it (the parts using the “echo” command) should work, but not the batch-specific parts (e.g. “goto”). But you should be able to convert it to a shell script and then it might work, or you may be able to emulate it within Ubuntu.

Edit: I've converted it, it appears to be incomplete. It appears to have converted the "if" parts, but not anything else. Let me know if it works (I highly doubt it), I'll also try it personally. I hope it helps. (Moderators,  please update this answer with a fully converted script if possible.)

```
export -a guessnum=0
export -a answer=${RANDOM}
echo Welcome to the Guessing Game! 
echo ""
echo Try and Guess my Number! 
echo ""
echo ""
export -p guess=
export -a guessnum=${guessnum} +1
if ${guess% GTR %answer} echo Lower! 
if ${guess% LSS %answer} echo Higher! 
if ${guess% EQU %answer} echo EQUAL
goto top
:equal
echo Congratulations, You guessed right!!! 
echo ""
echo It took you ${guessnum} guesses. 
echo ""
pause
```

Comment: weird that there is no .bat batch file converter to linux .sh script or executable in the repo

Comment: because it is impossible @BasLamerichs both are piles of hacks. Besides that: it is impossible to convert external calls anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you install `wine` (see https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu for more information) to your system you can use your batch file.

After you have installed `wine` (use the `sudo apt install wine64` command to install it); run the command `wineconsole`. A window similar to the Windows "command prompt" will appear. Change to the directory containing your Windows batch file and run it by entering its name.

Or, you can switch to the directory containing your batch file in a Linux terminal (use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut to open a terminal) and run `wineconsole your_batch_file.bat` directly.

***Note***: Your batch file contains an error: You should put a `:top` label after the 8th line.

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu, so I don't understand anything about 'sudo' or terminal. Is there a way to download wine without using the terminal e.g. Ubuntu Store?

Comment: Yes. Search for **wine**. On the list displayed scroll towards the end. You will see an icon of glass with wine () and the title **Wine**. Install that.

Comment: I scrolled to the bottom of the list, but I just found a lot of apps with a bird logo